# E = $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \vert x^2y \geq 0\}$ Border of E?

Tags: general-topology

We use the usual euclidean topology, and I want to find the border of E = $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \vert x^2y \geq 0\}$ with respect to $\mathbb{R}^2$. I know that the border of E is: Border(E) = Closure(E) $\setminus$ Interior(E). I also know that Border(E) = Closure(E) $\cap$ Closure(X $\setminus$ E).

I try to use the first one, but I'm struggling because I know that this set is closed, but I do not know how to find the interior part of it.

Any hints?

EDIT: Second formula was wrong.

Comment: The last equality is not true.

Comment: Ouch, going to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mathring E=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,x^2y>0\}.$$

Comment: If I understand this correctly then the border of E is just equal to $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \vert x^2y = 0\}$?

Comment: @LudovicoBessi Yes, that's right.

Comment: Is it equivalent to: $\{ y=0\} \cup \{ x=0, y \leq 0\}$?

Comment: @LudovicoBessi What do you mean with “equivalent”?

Comment: Is $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \vert x^2y=0\}$ the same set of points as $\{y=0\} \cup \{x=0, y \leq 0\}$? The one with the union is the solution proposed by my professor, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @LudovicoBessi No. The boundary is$$\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\middle|\,x\neq0\wedge y=\frac1{x^2}\right\}\cup\left\{(0,y)\,\middle|\,y\in\mathbb R\right\}.$$